# Запрос к Google Play API, python

Tags: python, google-play

Мне по задаче необходимо спарсить с play market'a следующую информацию: названия приложений, рейтинг, кол-во скачиваний и др. информацию. Решил собирать всю инфу через google play API, но столкнулся с тем, что совершенно не имею представления что нужно спросить у API, чтобы он ответил названием всех приложений (ру сегмента) и информацией о них. Если тут есть разбирающиеся в этой теме люди, пожалуйста, просвятите как это делается. Заранее спасибо.